# Problem with addition and macro argument

Tags: macros, dimension-expressions

I need to use a formula like this:

```
y = 1.8pt * x + 1.5pt
```

inside a macro, where `x` is a scalar macro argument. My idea:

```
\kern \advance #1\dimexpr1.8pt\relax by \dimexpr1.5pt\relax
```

This doesn't really work, the `\advance` command seems wrongly formatted.

Comment: This is a duplicate of something that is really not easy to find on this site

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\kern` requires a `<dimen>` after it; it can also be a `<skip>`, that is coerced to a `<dimen>` by removing the `plus` and `minus` parts.

A `<dimen>`, according to the TeXbook, is basically either an internal dimen register (for instance `\parindent`, `\dimen2` or any control sequence defined with `\newdimen`) or an explicit specification `<decimal number><unit of measure>` (I'll gloss over the finer details).

Also `<factor><dimen register>` is allowed. So `\kern 0.5\parindent` is a legal specification.

You can't follow `\kern` with the instructions to get a length, so an assignment instruction such as `\advance` is illegal.

However, e-TeX introduced a new possibility: a `<dimen>` can also be an expression computed with `\dimexpr`. The syntax is extended so that `\dimexpr<dimen expression>` can replace an internal dimension in the rules above.

Thus `\kern 0.3\dimexpr 1.7pt+\baselineskip\relax` (just a silly example) is legal when e-TeX is used, which is the case in all modern TeX distributions when running (pdf)LaTeX, XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

`\dimexpr` calls can be nested; the `\relax` at the end is optional and marks the end of the expression, so that TeX won't continue to search for terms belonging to the current expression when it finds `\relax` (that will vanish).

Therefore you're looking for

```
\kern \dimexpr 1.5pt + #1\dimexpr 1.8pt\relax\relax
```

The alternative way without `\dimexpr` is

```
\dimen0=1.8pt
\dimen0=#1\dimen0
\advance\dimen0 by 1.5pt
\kern\dimen0
```

using the scratch register `\dimen0`, or with the “official” LaTeX commands `\setlength` and `\addtolength`. For such a computation, it's not necessary to allocate a new register, but it doesn't hurt.

What's the difference between the two approaches? The `\dimexpr` way is certainly more flexible; but remind that division with `\divide` truncates, while `\dimexpr(dimen expression)/<integer>\relax` rounds. This might be a factor in some computation (but this is more relevant in `\numexpr`, because dimensions are actually integer multiples of scaled points, so the rounding happens at the scaled point level). Indeed e-TeX provides `\numexpr`, `\dimexpr`, `\glueexpr` and `\muexpr` to operate on numbers, dimensions, glues and muglues.

---

By the way, `\advance` *must* be followed by an internal register name (`\count`, `\dimen`, `\skip` or `\muskip` type), so `\advance\dimexpr...` is illegal also with e-TeX, which would balk with

```
! You can't use `\dimexpr' after \advance.
```

Comment: Thanks for the long explanation, I know too little about "registers" and such. Normally working with general purpose statically typed programming languages, things like R and LaTeX will clearly remain a mystery to me till I die.

Answer (score 1):

The following works:

```
\kern \dimexpr 1.5pt + #1\dimexpr 1.8pt\relax\relax
```

Answer (score 0):

Old school:

```
\setlength(\y}{1.8pt}
\setlength{\y}{#1\y}
\addtolength{\y}{1.5pt}
```